# Getting the latest version from cdnjs

Tags: javascript, cdn

I would like to pull the latest version from my Content Delivery Network.

Q: Instead of saying:

```
cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.js
```

Is there way to say something like:

```
cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/modernizr.js
```

And NOT include the version number?

Comment: jsDelivr uses the same CloudFlare backend (among others) and supports version aliasing (latest, semver, etc.). https://github.com/jsdelivr/jsdelivr#version-aliasing

Comment: jsDelivr doesn't support getting the file from releases, does it? Because I can't make it work. The file isn't in the folder structure, only in releases/download.

Answer (score 11):

You don't want to do this. CDN is all about aggressive caching. E.g. CDN servers are sending far in the future `Expires` headers to make sure the resource remains cached.

If there was a URL always pointing to the most recent version, all your caching goes crazy. Some clients still see the old version while others get the new one. In fact adding a version or other tag is a known technique to make sure new versions are fetched and no caching is involved on the client side. Just look at the source code of the page you are looking at:

```
http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=655f0a867d03
```

Without the noise in `v` parameter StackOverflow team could never have both: fantastic caching and ability to push new versions quickly and reliably.

Last but not least - are you sure you want to blindly load newest script version with unknown bugs and deprecations? Taking the first part into consideration, even if someone is complaining, it's hard to tell which version is he really using.

Comment: I was burned once when jQuery did that with their attr selector.  But I haven't learned my lesson yet, so yes, I always want the latest version.  And I never want it cached, so that's a good idea to put a unique url parameter in the script reference.

Comment: And I never want it minimized.

Comment: @Phillip: so why bother with CDN if you don't want caching and minification?

Comment: To always get the latest version.

Comment: There are uses for the latest version, without caching and minification. Mine is a proof of concept dev environment, having the latest version allows me to go back later to see if it works with newer versions.

Comment: So how do I get the latest version using cdnjs?