# Dynamic Content Delivery Network (CDN) in HTML links

Tags: html, bokeh, cdn

Background:

I have a web app that references many `CDN`'s in my `HTML` front end. Full disclosure, I am a novice dev at best so very likely that the answer is very simple.

At the time of writing (Oct 2020), I am using, among others, the following CDN:

```
<link href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.0.2.min.css">
```

Question:

Is there a more dynamic way to link this CDN so that I don't have to manually update the version number (`2.0.2`) if and when it changes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the latest version from cdnjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801334/getting-the-latest-version-from-cdnjs)

Answer (score 1):

If your question is:

> How can I ask Bokeh itself for the matching CDN links that correspond to the current installed Python package version?

Then this is the simplest way:

```
In [1]: from bokeh.resources import CDN

In [2]: CDN.js_files
Out[2]:
['https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.2.1.min.js',
 'https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.2.1.min.js',
 'https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-2.2.1.min.js']
```

Note that that just lists *all possible* resource URLs. If you aren't using widgets or tables then you don't need those files.

Also note:

- The official URL changed to `cdn.bokeh.org` several years ago. The "pydata" links will continue to work, but everyone should prefer the `bokeh.org` ones in any new code.
- There are not any separate CSS files any more in recent versions of Bokeh, on the JS files.

---

The above assumes you are using Bokeh from *Python*, where the Python and JS versions need to be matched. If you are using BokehJS directly (not super common, but it happens) then you should just pick whatever version you intend to use, and update it intentionally/manually, as others have suggested.

Comment: This suggestion is fine if you are generating the HTML using python, but I have a large web-app with predefined front-end HTML where I embed my bokeh graphs. Perhaps you are saying that I don't need to explicitly add the ```link``` in html?. If so, great, but what about other CDNs like ```bootstrap```? In summary, I think everyone agrees that there is no solution and it should be a manual process

Comment: That's what I said.

Answer (score 0):

A very similar question has been asked before on this subject here

[Getting the latest version from cdnjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801334/getting-the-latest-version-from-cdnjs)

and it's generally not a good idea to adopt this practice.

Always using the latest version can expose you to bugs, unwanted behaviour. If the version you are using is stable, then its probably best to stick to it.

Comment: Bokeh is published to its own CDN at `cdn.bokeh.org` and that should be preferred as the official source.

Comment: "Always using the latest version can expose you to bugs". This is actually a good point, hence my upvote.